# Single Price Auction

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, auction-theory

I am self-studying the following question: there is a bag with unknown value (can be negative). Everyone bids a price and whoever bids the highest wins the bag. Design the optimal strategy. This is a quick open question and we can make reasonable assumptions as we want.

I decided to model it as a first-auction game. So suppose the value of the good is standard Normal $\theta \sim N(0, 1)$. Each bidder $i$ bids $y_i = \theta + e_i$ where $e_i$ is i.i.d. standard Normal. By using this, my expected payoff is $E(\theta - y_i | y_i \geq y_j, \forall j).$ However it seems hard to write down this expectation term. Can anyone help with this

Comment: Are the bidders risk averse at all?  If so, why would they add a random value to their bid?  If not, why would they bid anything besides $\mathbb{E}[\theta]$?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would surmise that each bidder is going to realize that the expected (i.e. average) value of the item is $(0)$.  So, not only is there no apparent profit in making a positive bid, there is no apparent profit in bidding $(0)$.

So, I would assume that all bidders accept the above analysis, and all bidders believe that all other bidders accept the above analysis.

Therefore, the only hope for profit is to make a negative bid that has a small absolute value.

As you increase the size of the bid that you are contemplating, (i.e. as your bid approaches $0$ from below), then two things are happening:

- You are increasing the probability that your bid will be the winning bid.
- You are decreasing the profit that you will realize, if your bid is the winning bid.

If my competitor was a robot or android, then I would expect my competitor to bid something like $- 10^{-(100)}.$

In a real world setting, I would bid $(-1)$ and hope that all of the other bidders are too panicked to make a rational bid, like $-(0.5).$